# Transfer the license agreements from my workstation to Azure Pipeline agent

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, android-sdk-manager

I am using Azure Pipeline in order to execute CI on my Android projects. Since yesterday, the CI failed to build apps with the following message :

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>       build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
>   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Because the agent is directly managed by Microsoft (Hosted VS2017 agent) I cannot run a command line manually in order to accept the missing licenses.

As suggested by gradle, I tried to create a task in order to copy the licenses from my workstation to the Azure Pipeline one.

Here the steps :

- I have added the licenses from my android-sdk home to the source code of the android app
- I have added a task to the pipeline in order to copy theses licenses files to the licenses directory of the pipeline workstation.

Here a screenshot of the the task in azure pipeline :

[image]

The copy of this file seems to be done correctly according to the logs :

> [section]Starting: Copy Files to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\
>   ============================================================================== Task         : Copy Files Description  : Copy files from source folder
>   to target folder using match patterns (The match patterns will only
>   match file paths, not folder paths) Version      : 2.117.2 Author
>   : Microsoft Corporation Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708389)
>   ============================================================================== found 6 files Cleaning target folder: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\ Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\android-googletv-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\android-googletv-license Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\android-sdk-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\android-sdk-license Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\android-sdk-preview-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\android-sdk-preview-license Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\google-gdk-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\google-gdk-license Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\intel-android-extra-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\intel-android-extra-license Copying
>   D:\a\1\s\licenses\mips-android-sysimage-license to C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\mips-android-sysimage-license
>   [section]Finishing: Copy Files to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses\

But the issue is still present. Note that this copy task is done before the gradle one.

Any idea in order to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, @rolandl. Something in Android SDK licensing changed on Windows.  We have a longer-term fix, but here’s a workaround until the fix reaches all of production:

1. Add a [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=vsts) step to the very beginning of your pipeline. Set the inline PowerShell script to be the following, which updates the Android licenses on the VS2017 virtual machine:

   Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -Force

   dir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses'

   $base64Content = "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"

   $content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($base64Content)

   Set-Content -Path .\android-sdk-licenses.zip -Value $content -Encoding Byte

   Expand-Archive -Path .\android-sdk-licenses.zip -DestinationPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' -Force

   dir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses'
2. Verify that the PowerShell step runs at the start of your build and the rest of the build succeeds again.

Comment: Hi David ! It works ! Thank you for your help ! Can you explain how your `base64Content` is generated ? It can help in order to potentially fixed a similar issue in the future :)